# Creating relationship class with ArcPy using GlobalID?

Tags: arcpy, relationship-class, error-000800

I'm trying to create a relationship class with Python using a GlobalID.

When I use Python it gives me the error:

> Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid. ERROR 000800: The value
>   is not a member of GLOBALID. Failed to execute
>   (CreateRelationshipClass).

When I try to use the Create Relationship Class tool through the Toolbox, I get the same error. If I select GlobalID as the primary key, it will ONLY let me select a GlobalID as the foreign key. It will not let me select a GUID of my choice.

But when I'm in ArcCatalog and right click the Dataset and go to `New > Relationship Class`...

It works!

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I found out the bug that was logged for this is NIM082537.

You can follow the status of it here:
http://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/role/beta10_1/TklNMDgyNTM3

It might be necessary to copy/paste URL into address bar.

Comment: The link is broken, use https://support.esri.com/fr/bugs/nimbus/TklNMDgyNTM3
The status of the bug indicates that it is fixed in version 10.6.1.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround that seemed to help in some cases for me was using time.sleep(10) between the creation of GlobalIDs/fields and calling CreateRelationshipClass_management. It only helped some of the time, though.

The best answer I found was using 2to3 to port my code into the arcpy packaged with arcgispro (on python3.4), and it is now successfully producing both one_to_many and many_to_many relationships based on GlobalID and parent GUID reference fields, and the GDB it produces works perfectly in Arcmap. HTH